# markerCluster one marker for a group

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am using [markerCluster](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) and it works great.

Here is the code how it works with 2 markers:

```
  window.onload = function() {
      // cluster marker
      var clusterMarker = [];

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 50, 3),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'terrain'
      });


      // Some sample data
      var sampleData = [{lat:50, lng:3}, {lat:50, lng:3.02}];


      for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i ++) {

        var point = sampleData[i];
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

        // create marker at location
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });

        // needed to cluster marker
        clusterMarker.push(marker);
      }

      new MarkerClusterer(map, clusterMarker, {imagePath: 'images/m', maxZoom: 15});
    }
```

and the result on different zoom levels:

[image][image]

If I zoom out, markerCluster counts the number of markers in one area. I would like to change it such that some marker represents multiple persons. So if I have one big marker that represents 21 persons, and a second marker that represents 1 person, then if I zoom out I would like to see the number 22 on the blue marker, and the big marker should have 21 on it. Is something like that possible?

So for example, I would like to get the following result, even if I just use two markers:
[image] [image]

Comment: can you attach screenshots of what you've got now, and what you'd like it to look like?  Also it might help if you added some of your code here too

Comment: possibly related question: [Markerclusterer set marker cluster icon depending on markers inside it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375173/markerclusterer-set-marker-cluster-icon-depending-on-markers-inside-it)

Comment: @duncan I added picture and code, hope its more clear now.

Comment: You probably want to use the MarkerClusterer in conjunction with something like MarkerWithLabel to add labels to the markers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/markerwithlabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a "calculator" function that does what you want (sums the property of the marker that indicates the "number of people".

Documentation for "calculator" function.  Returns an Object with the properties:

- `text` (the text to appear on the cluster)
- `index` (the index into the styles array to access the style for that cluster.

```
/**
 *  The function for calculating the cluster icon image.
 *
 *  @param {Array.<google.maps.Marker>} markers The markers in the clusterer.
 *  @param {number} numStyles The number of styles available.
 *  @return {Object} A object properties: 'text' (string) and 'index' (number).
 *  @private
 */
MarkerClusterer.prototype.calculator_ = function(markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var count = markers.length;
  var dv = count;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
  return {
    text: count,
    index: index
  };
};
```

If you add a property to your data, "number", you could do something like this:

**code snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // cluster marker
  var clusterMarker = [];

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50, 3),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });


  // Some sample data
  var sampleData = [{
    lat: 50,
    lng: 3,
    number: 20

  }, {
    lat: 50,
    lng: 3.02,
    number: 1
  }];


  for (var i = 0; i < sampleData.length; i++) {

    var point = sampleData[i];
    var location = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);

    // create marker at location
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      number: sampleData[i].number,
      title: "" + sampleData[i].number
    });

    // needed to cluster marker
    clusterMarker.push(marker);
  }

  var clusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, clusterMarker, {
    imagePath: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m',
    maxZoom: 15
  });

  clusterer.setCalculator(function(markers, numStyles) {
    var index = 0;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].number) {
        count += markers[i].number;
      } else {
        count++;
      }
    }
    var dv = markers.length;
    while (dv !== 0) {
      dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
      index++;
    }

    index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
    return {
      text: count,
      index: index
    };
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect!! That was exactly what I needed! Thank you!