# set marker cluster icon depending on markers inside it

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've put together a map with clusters. The [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375173/markerclusterer-set-marker-cluster-icon-depending-on-markers-inside-it) was that cluster's color should depend on the color of markers inside: if there is a red marker, cluster is red; no red, but there is a yellow marker, cluster is yellow; no red and yellow markers, cluster is blue.

This only works as expected at specific zoom levels. Fully zoomed out it shows blue cluster, however there are red markers in there, so I expect a red cluster. When I start to zoom in and the map shows multiple clusters, most look right, but in some instances this offending behavior repeats, it will group red/yellow/blue markers into blue cluster, I expect red. Same with Yellow + Blue  markers should form a yellow cluster, not blue.

According to [this](https://nooshu.github.io/blog/2012/10/03/marker-cluster-calculator-for-google-maps-v3/) setCalculator function runs for each cluster individually, therefore I was expecting consistent behavior, but instead we have mixed results.

```js
    function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, 4),
            zoom:6,
            mapTypeControlOptions:"roadmap"
        });

        var markers = [];

        // make random red, yellow, blue markers
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(), 4.11 - Math.random());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng, 
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
                label: i,
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(),4.11 - Math.random());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng, 
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png',
                label: i,
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(),4.11 - Math.random());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng, 
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
                label: i,
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);
        }

        // match cluster icon to markers
        var calc = function(markers, numStyles) {
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("red.png") > -1) {
                    return {text: markers.length, index: 3}; // index of red
                }else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("yellow.png") > -1) {
                return {text: markers.length, index: 2}; // index of yellow
                }else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("green.png") > -1) {
                    return {text: markers.length, index: 1};// index of blue
                }
            }
        }

        // define cluster icons
        var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15, styles: [{
                height: 50,
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png",
                width: 50
            },
            {
                height: 50,
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m2.png",
                width: 50
            },
            {
                height: 50,
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m3.png",
                width: 50
            }]
        };
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
        markerCluster.setCalculator(calc);
    }
```

```css
    #map {
            height: 80%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
```

```html
    <script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.42&key=AIzaSyA4PP1O36qWCzer8K3VFyjf0uxRs4WVNFo&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>

    <div id="map"></div>
```

UPDATE: changed marker icons to be more distinguishable from cluster icons.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.  Random markers that look the same as the clusters, it is very difficult to reproduce and debug the issue.  A single case that demonstrates the issue would be more helpful.

Comment: Run the snippet, you will see blue cluster. I expect to see red cluster. I think the issue is reproduced.

Comment: Changed icons for random markers so they don't look the same as the clusters, and reduced total number of markers to be more readable, as requested.

Comment: Made it much easier to debug.  The randomness still makes it behave differently every time, but at least it was possible to see the (or a) issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your issues is your calculator function.  You want it to return "red" if there are any red markers in the cluster, yellow if there are any yellow markers but no red ones, and blue otherwise.  Write the code to do that:

```
// match cluster icon to markers
var calc = function(markers, numStyles) {
    // default to blue
    var highestPriorityColor = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("red.png") > -1) {
            // if any markers are red, will be red, can return result
            return {text: markers.length, index: 3}; // index of red
        } else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("yellow.png") > -1) {
            // if any markers are yellow, update it to yellow if it is blue
            if (highestPriorityColor < 2)
                highestPriorityColor = 2; // index of yellow
        } /* else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("green.png") > -1) {
            // ignore green markers (leave it whatever color it is, defaults to blue)
        } */
    }
    // return result once complete processing all the markers
    return {text: markers.length, index: highestPriorityColor}; // index of chosen cluster
}
```

**zoomed out**

[image: zoomed all out, red cluster]

**zoom in**

[image: zoom in once]

**zoom in on red "17" cluster**
[image: zoom in on red 17 cluster]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51, 4),
    zoom: 6,
    mapTypeControlOptions: "roadmap"
  });

  var markers = [];

  // make random red, yellow, blue markers
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(), 4.11 - Math.random());
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png',
      label: "" + i,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(), 4.11 - Math.random());
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png',
      label: "" + i,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.11 - Math.random(), 4.11 - Math.random());
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png',
      label: "" + i,
      map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);
  }

  // match cluster icon to markers
  var calc = function(markers, numStyles) {
    // default to blue
    var highestPriorityColor = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("red.png") > -1) {
        // if any markers are red, will be red, can return result
        return {
          text: markers.length,
          index: 3
        }; // index of red
      } else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("yellow.png") > -1) {
        // if any markers are yellow, update it to yellow if it is blue
        if (highestPriorityColor < 2)
          highestPriorityColor = 2; // index of yellow
      }
      /* else if (markers[i].getIcon().indexOf("green.png") > -1) {
                 // ignore green markers (leave it whatever color it is, defaults to blue)
             } */
    }
    // return result once complete processing all the markers
    return {
      text: markers.length,
      index: highestPriorityColor
    }; // index of chosen cluster
  }

  // define cluster icons
  var mcOptions = {
    gridSize: 50,
    maxZoom: 15,
    styles: [{
        height: 50,
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m1.png",
        width: 50
      },
      {
        height: 60,
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m2.png",
        width: 60
      },
      {
        height: 70,
        url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlearchive/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m3.png",
        width: 70
      }
    ]
  };
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
  markerCluster.setCalculator(calc);
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.42&key=AIzaSyA4PP1O36qWCzer8K3VFyjf0uxRs4WVNFo&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'd like to understand why my nested IF statements returned a  Blue cluster when there was a red marker inside, and your *highestPriorityColor* flag returns the correct color. Should I ask another question or could you say in a comment?

Comment: Your code returns the result based on the first marker.  Always (unless it is a weird color and doesn't match one of the `if` conditions).

Comment: I though it goes through all markers in a cluster with the FOR loop in both cases. I'll have to look into loops. Doesn't make sense at the moment. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Each of the `if` statements returns from the function, so if any of them return true, it will return after evaluating the first marker.